# Weird layout behavior in IE7 (scrollbar appearing where it shouldn't)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Here's teh codez:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            #pageContainer {
                min-width: 100%;
                float: left;
                background-color: red;
            }
            #leftColumn {
                float: left;
                background-color: lime;
            }
            #rightColumn {
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageContainer">
            <div id="leftColumn">Left column</div>
            <div id="rightColumn">Right column</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On IE8/Opera/FF everything looks fine. If I take IE8 and turn on IE7 mode (standards compliant), suddenly a horizontal scrollbar appears. Suspiciously it is just as big as the left column. Any ideas?!

[image: Example]

Comment: is it happening in this http://jsfiddle.net/pexZm/ for you?

Comment: that's strange, doesn't happen for me on that jsfiddle

Comment: @Jaitsu - did you turn on IE7 mode? Note that IE8 handles it just fine.

Comment: Yeah even when turning on IE7 document mode it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions. On the right column, either:

- Remove `position: relative` if you don't need it.
- Or, keep that and add `zoom: 1`.

This is all about [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

Comment: Thank you, zoom: 1 fixed it! I do need the relative position.